# Heuristic timing out

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am currently taking an AI class on edx.org, and I would like to ask for some help. The project is a paceman game in which the pacman finds the path to get to all of the dots by itself. I am having some trouble with the heuristic function.

More info:
The autograder specifically says that the problem is with the heuristic; it says that I coded breadth first search correctly.
The wanted end result of the program is to find the best path for pacman to eat all of the dots.
The function returns the heuristic, which tells the search algorithm the cost of moving in a certain direction.

Here is my code:

```
def foodHeuristic(state, problem):

"""
Your heuristic for the FoodSearchProblem goes here.

This heuristic must be consistent to ensure correctness.  First, try to come
up with an admissible heuristic; almost all admissible heuristics will be
consistent as well.

If using A* ever finds a solution that is worse uniform cost search finds,
your heuristic is *not* consistent, and probably not admissible!  On the
other hand, inadmissible or inconsistent heuristics may find optimal
solutions, so be careful.

The state is a tuple ( pacmanPosition, foodGrid ) where foodGrid is a Grid
(see game.py) of either True or False. You can call foodGrid.asList() to get
a list of food coordinates instead.

If you want access to info like walls, capsules, etc., you can query the
problem.  For example, problem.walls gives you a Grid of where the walls
are.

If you want to *store* information to be reused in other calls to the
heuristic, there is a dictionary called problem.heuristicInfo that you can
use. For example, if you only want to count the walls once and store that
value, try: problem.heuristicInfo['wallCount'] = problem.walls.count()
Subsequent calls to this heuristic can access
problem.heuristicInfo['wallCount']
"""
    position, foodGrid = state
    fh = 0
    bfsResults = search.breadthFirstSearch(problem) #bfs: breadth first search

    fh = len(bdsResults)

    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    print "Heuristic: " + str(fh)
    return fh
```

I am not too experienced with python, but it seems fine to me. When I run the autograder, when checking the heuristic, it times out. Please help!

Comment: The question is unanswerable for anyone not knowing the course. What exactly times out? The breadth search? What are you supposed to return? Did you wrote `breadthFirstSearch` yourself? Or is all of that the template that was provided to you? The problem mentions A* so you are probably supposed to use something quicker than breadth first search.

Comment: My apologies. I have updated the question, and added more info. I tried using A* search, and the autograder still times out when grading the heuristic section of the project.

Comment: Well, for starters it looks like you might have a type. I assume you intended to be setting fh = len(bfsResults) rather than len(bdsResults)? Does that solve the problem? If not, I'd guess that they want a better heuristic than just the return of bfs.

Comment: I saw that error soon after I posted this question. I fixed it, and the autograder still times out. Also, when I try to run the program itself (without the autograder) python idle freezes and ultimately crashes.

Answer (score 1):

A* search works because it incorporates information about what is likely to be a good path into the search process, and is able to search for better paths first and so arrive at the goal state faster. Breadth-first search, which is currently all that you're basing your heuristic off of, provides minimal information about what options are more promising than others.

As you've probably learned, A* heuristics need to be admissible. I.e. they can never overestimate the distance to a node. For the purposes of coming up with such heuristics, it's often helpful to think about constraints on the real problem that can be relaxed. So, for instance, you might decide to ignore walls in calculating your heuristic (I don't know if that's actually a good idea or not).

It looks like you've got a lot of data to try using. See if you can come up with a more informative heuristic. If you find a good enough one, you should be able to find the goal state before the heuristic times out.